# Port number is removed when clicking a url in localhost/server

Tags: php, laravel, href

I have a very strange scenario where I provide a href url in my page with a port number in my localhost and server. I have a link which is `https://localhost:8242/tagurl?tagid=2/view/`, I can observe that it is the url my browser is using when clicked but when the page is loaded, it is changed to `localhost/tagurl?tag_id=2/view/` resulting a page not found error.

**UPDATE**

Link can be viewed including the port number if copying it directly to the browser but not when url is clicked.

Someone has idea on this?

Comment: Sounds like some sort of automatic redirect – verify by checking what happens with the original request in your browser dev tools. If there isn’t a redirect in there, then of course it might also be something client-side that redirects elsewhere after the page was loaded, mis-configured JavaScript or something like that. We can only guess with the information we have here so far.

Comment: Anyone has come up to this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. After a long way of testing, I have figured it out. I don't know about the reason but I have to do it this way.

`https://localhost:8242/tagurl/?tagid=2/view/`

I just added a front slash. Without front slash and just directly typing the url, `https://localhost:8242/tagurl?tagid=2/view/` works well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `APP_URL` in your `.env` file is configured correctly. It is default `http://localhost` without a port.